# FreeMarker template error with csrf

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, freemarker

It was necessary in the project to configure authentication with Spring Security + Freemarker. I have login page

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="_csrf" 
type="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="error" type="java.util.Optional<String>" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav role="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1>Log in</h1>
<p>You can use: demo@localhost / demo</p>
<form role="form" action="/login" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
<div>
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required autofocus/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me"/>
</div>
<button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This page is handled by LoginController

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
}
}
```

The configuration Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "projectpackages.janus")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRATOR")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
}

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
}
```

When I turn to the login page, freemarker throws an exception

```
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> _csrf  [in template "login.ftl" at line 21, column 34]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: ${_csrf.parameterName}  [in template "login.ftl" at line 21, 
column 32]
----
```

Help to understand the possible reasons of this error. Search on the Internet did not succeed(

Comment: On client check what is stored in the `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>`. Looks like it's not filled properly. See also https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Comment: How can I check they are filled in? The error throws as soon as I go to the page